# oracle apex 18.2 images storing and displaying in forms as well as reports

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am using oracle apex 18.2 with oracle xe version.I want to display the Employees Images as display card etc. I want recommendations for storing images as per database version, what would be the best practice for storing images either in database as BLOB or it should be in File system.In both cases how can i display in Interactive report or as display card.I have done some googling but i am not much clear regarding the Story as per Limited Version of My Database.

Comment: XE you use allows 12GB of user data, doesn't it? Do you really expect to store that much images? If so, you won't have any more room for *real* data so - store images in file system. Otherwise, store them in the database. I use both options (database/file system), both work OK.

Comment: Can you please share any example of Storing Images in File system and displaying in Classic Report for Oracle Apex 18